# Facing multiple issue when I try to start on minikube on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, minikube

I am facing lot of issue to start minikube on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 in order to set-up kubernates. Initially I was getting below issue related crictl when i run the command `minikube start --vm-driver=none`

[image]

Somehow I was able to resolve the above issue by installing crictl and adding path to user/bin. Now when I run this command again `minikube start --vm-driver=none` then I am getting the below issue
[image]

I also try this command to start minikube but result are same `minikube start --driver=none`

Below are the step which I follow to set-up minikubes

1. first i install kubetcl and set path curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && chmod +x ./kubectl && sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
2. then minikube curl -LO [https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl](https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/%60curl) -s [https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl](https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt%60/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl) && chmod +x kubectl && sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/
3. After that i install conntrack
4. then did update everything apt-get update -y
5. I run this command `minikube start --vm-driver=none`

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: In kubernates, first it all required set-up to start working, I know it's not related to programming , but to get started I need to configure kubernates then I will do some programming

Comment: "*I know it's not related to programming*" - ["*if your question  ...  is a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development** ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- "*but to get started I need to configure kubernates then I will do some programming*" - One does not need a k8s cluster in order to program.

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The new error gave you two new suggestions. However, just use EKS instead